# What is the difference between a deferred annuity and an endowment policy?

Tags: insurance, terminology, annuity

This is a follow up question on [Financial product where the investor makes regular contributions and receives a lump sum](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/144116/financial-product-where-the-investor-makes-regular-contributions-and-receives-a). "Deferred annuity" and "endowment policy" are the financial products that fit the description.

Definition of endowment policy on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endowment_policy):

> An endowment policy is a life insurance contract designed to pay a lump sum after a specific term (on its 'maturity') or on death.

Definition of deferred annuity on [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/deferredannuity.asp):

> A deferred annuity is a contract with an insurance company that promises to pay the owner a regular income, or a lump sum, at some future date.

What is the difference between a deferred annuity and an endowment policy? Are they the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

An endowment policy pays out a lump sum at maturity or death, whichever comes first. No regular income possible.

A (deferred) annuity pays the owner a guaranteed regular income, i.e., from age 65 until death. Sometimes a partial lump sum is returned in the event of the owner's "premature" death.